# "Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. \end{frame}" in beamer class

Tags: tables, beamer

I am getting this error but I do not know what is wrong with this part:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
\title{Test}
\author{Author}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Initial model: average costs}
large table 1
\begin{center}
    \resizebox{9.5cm}{!}{
        \begin{table}[H]
            \centering
            \begin{tabular}{|c|p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{2mm}|}
                \hline
                $j\setminus k$
                &0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25&26&27&28&29&30\\
                \hline
                0&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1\\
                1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1\\
                2&0&0&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1\\
                3&0&0&0&0&0&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1\\
                4&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1\\
                5&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1\\
                6&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&1&1&1&1\\
                7&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
                8&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
                \hline
            \end{tabular}
        \end{table}
    }
\end{center}
large table 2:
\begin{center}
\resizebox{9.5cm}{!}{
\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{2mm}|}
        \hline
        $j\setminus k$
        &0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25&26&27&28&29&30\\
        \hline
        0&0&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1\\
        1&0&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1\\
        2&0&0&0&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1\\
        3&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1\\
        4&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1\\
        5&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1\\
        6&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&1&1&1\\
        7&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
        8&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
}
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

(I do not know how to compile this on the TeX exchange)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the use of `\resizebox`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
\title{Test}
\author{Author}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Initial model: average costs}
large table 1
        \begin{table}
            \centering \tiny \setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}
            \begin{tabular}{|c|*{31}{c}|}
                \hline
                $j\setminus k$
                &0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25&26&27&28&29&30\\
                \hline
                0&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1\\
                1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1\\
                2&0&0&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1\\
                3&0&0&0&0&0&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1\\
                4&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1\\
                5&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1\\
                6&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&1&1&1&1\\
                7&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
                8&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
                \hline
            \end{tabular}
        \end{table}
large table 2:
\begin{table}
    \centering \tiny \setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}
\begin{tabular}{|c|*{31}{c}|}
        \hline
        $j\setminus k$
        &0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25&26&27&28&29&30\\
        \hline
        0&0&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1\\
        1&0&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1\\
        2&0&0&0&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1\\
        3&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1\\
        4&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1\\
        5&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1\\
        6&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&1&1&1\\
        7&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
        8&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

It does IMHO not make too much sense to (i) wrap the `table` into `center` (you are using `\centering` anyway) and (ii) to wrap the `\resizebox` around a `table` environment (rather than the `tabular`). The following does not throw errors but is still far from pretty.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
\title{Test}
\author{Author}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Initial model: average costs}
large table 1
        \begin{table}
            \centering
            \resizebox{9.5cm}{!}{\begin{tabular}{|c|p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{2mm}|}
                \hline
                $j\setminus k$
                &0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25&26&27&28&29&30\\
                \hline
                0&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1\\
                1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1\\
                2&0&0&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1\\
                3&0&0&0&0&0&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1\\
                4&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1\\
                5&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1\\
                6&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&1&1&1&1\\
                7&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
                8&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
                \hline
            \end{tabular}}
        \end{table}
large table 2:
\begin{table}
    \centering
\resizebox{9.5cm}{!}{\begin{tabular}{|c|p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{0mm}p{2mm}|}
        \hline
        $j\setminus k$
        &0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25&26&27&28&29&30\\
        \hline
        0&0&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1\\
        1&0&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1\\
        2&0&0&0&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1\\
        3&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1\\
        4&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1\\
        5&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1\\
        6&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&1&1&1\\
        7&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
        8&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}}
\end{table}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]